# Progressr to display iteration in pmap in R

Tags: r

I have a rather complex pmap function in R and I would like to simply display what iteration number pmap is currently executing.  I think the "progressr" package is likely what I want to use, but all of the documentation and examples I'm finding seem rather cumbersome.  I have a dataframe of variables that I feed into my pmap function.  The dataframe is called 'crosslist', and the pmap function is below:

```
library(purrr)

results <-  pmap(crosslist, safely(function(variable1, variable2, ...., variable 10) {  

#do a lot of calculations inside pmap that is a function of variable1, variable 2, ....., variable10
    
}, otherwise = "NA"))
```

I think I use the with_progress function (from library(progressr)) prior to {, but I'm having problems getting it to work.  All I would like is for somewhere in R (likely the console) to display what iteration the pmap function is currently processing.

To use this with_progress, do I simply place it as follows:

```
results <-  pmap(crosslist, safely(function(variable1, variable2, ...., variable 10) with_progress({  

#do a lot of calculations inside pmap that is a function of variable1, variable 2, ....., variable10
    
}), otherwise = "NA"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code from `pmap` to `map` and loop over index of each row which you can print in the console to know which line is current being processed. You can use it as :

```
library(purrr)

results <-  map(seq(nrow(crosslist)), safely(function(i) {  
  print(i)
  var <- crosslist[i, ]
  #You can access variable1, variable2 by var[['variable1']], var[['variable2']]
}, otherwise = "NA"))
```